# Simple HTML jQuery scroller/slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm looking for a horizontal jquery scroller, that can contain any HTML content and scroll automatically. Feel free to advise of any you use in projects that would be suitable.

Ideally it's quite stripped down, so I can just get #slide1 to scroll to #scroll2, and those DIV's having any html content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle) plugin or [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) should be your friend:)

If you want to scroll only an inline list Jcarousel is perfect, but it's not suitable for you, if you want to scroll a grid things, like an image thumbnail gallery  with x row,and y column.

Answer (score 2):

You get one good slider here

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Comment: This one I can totally recommend. It's good, fast and easy to use!

Comment: Amusing. Nivo doesn't support HTML does it? Captions only.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the cycle plugin - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Specifically look at the examples at the bottom of the page.